# Stand alone TFS bug tracking client

Tags: tfs, bug-tracking

I think TFS is an awesome product, however I'm now using a combination of Test Manager and Visual Studio to Create / Track bugs.

As far as I know - Test Manager does not give you a bug overview dashboard.

Visual Studio has the ability to create Queries which gives you the ability to create powerful queries to search for bugs, but all of this is handled inside the Visual Studio IDE, imo better used for coding.

What I'm looking for is a stand alone client that I can use to give me dashboard views of bugs captured in TFS, where I can customise the area paths, etc.

Comment: TFS sits on top of Sharepoint, and comes with Reporting Services as well - could you use the project portal for your dashboard?

Comment: @Rowland - Ideally not something web based. Just want a detached client side app.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Excel with the Team Foundation add-in](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181675.aspx) if the users are comfortable with that. You will need to install Team Explorer first though. You can then create any dashboards that you want using Excel charts against tfs query results within an Excel table. The users will then also have the ability to publish updates to work items.

If you don't need updating you can connect Excel directly to the TFS Cube and build dashboard against it as in my post [TFS Business Intelligence Reporting](http://mgrowan.wordpress.com/2009/01/20/tfs-business-intelligence-reporting/).